# how to set datasource connection properties in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have multiple datasources in spring boot application configured as below :

```
spring:
  application:
    name: myapp
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
  datasource-secondary:
      type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
      jdbc-url: jdbc:oracle:thin:...
      username: ...
      password: ...
      driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
      connection-timeout: 20000
      maximum-pool-size: 10
      pool-name: secondary-pool
  datasource-primary:
      type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
      jdbc-url:  jdbc:postgresql...
      username:  ...
      password: ...
      driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
      connection-timeout: 20000
      maximum-pool-size: 10
      pool-name: primary-pool

@EnableTransactionManagement
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource-secondary")
    public DataSource secondaryDatasource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource-primary")
    public DataSource primaryDatasource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

@PostConstruct
    public void setUp() {
        System.setProperty("oracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion", "false");
        System.setProperty("oracle.jdbc.fanEnabled", "false");
    }

}
```

Since I have 1 datasource as oracle , I need to disable oracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion properties. Hence I tried to set using postconstruct, however this is not working when I am trying to run image of my application via docker.

I know I can set those vm arguments via docker-compose.yaml, however in uat environment , applications are not run using docker, only image is run from simple java command.

**How can I set those vm arguments in spring boot application so that it's image can run without any such failure?**

Added here those properties , but still it's not set.

[image]

Comment: Why you are not writing both database configuration in your ```application.properties``` file? Or do you need to use docker-compose file?

Comment: @Abdusoli I have mentioned the configuration in application.yml , docker is used to create image and nothing else

Comment: Once I used two databases: Oracle and Postgresql together. But I wrote configurations in ```application.properties``` file.

Comment: @Abdusoli how can I set oracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion in application.yml ?

Comment: @Abdusoli I added in application.yml but still it's not set

Comment: Why not use profiling for this this kind of job.

Comment: Add them to the datasource by prefing it with`spring.datasource-secondary.properties` and don't try to set it as yaml use the full name else it won't work.